# Is there any way to force a suicide in Risk of Rain?

Tags: risk-of-rain

I got stuck in the map "Temple of the Elders" after finding the Spirit artifact. I jumped down from there and got kind of stuck in nowhere.

Here is my current view. Music and time are still working but nothing else has any effect.

How can I end the game in such a way that I keep the artifact?
[image]

Edit: I'm camping it out. Maybe a jellyfish will kill me.
Edit2: Returned to main manu after 98 minutes via esc-key and "return to main menu". The game saved the artifact but nothing else.

Comment: `"Returned to main manu after 98 minutes. I got the artifact"` - Do you mean you were able to successfully get your character to die, and save your progress? Or do you mean you had to use the menu to return and weren't able to save your progress?

Comment: i used the menu. It saved the artifact, but nothing else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is unfortunately no legit way to intentionally "respawn" (as a suicide logically results in dying, which means that you lose your progress) besides returning to the main menu and starting a new session.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to cause your character to die, on the Temple of the Elders level there should be  [Archer Bugs](http://riskofrain.wikia.com/wiki/Archer_Bug). Can you wait around for some of them to spawn and simply let them attack you?

Comment: I waited but also they probably spawned they couldn't damage me.